# Basic webserver using sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have the following bare-bones server in order to make sure that I'm able to receive a socket connection:

```
import socket

HOST, PORT = '', 8888

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)
print(f'Serving HTTP on port {PORT} ...')
while True:
    print ('1 - start')
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request_data = client_connection.recv(1024)
    print(request_data.decode('utf-8'))
    client_connection.sendall(b"""HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nHello, World!\n""")
    client_connection.close()
    print ('2 - end')
```

And when I view it in Chrome, it loads the page, but doesn't return any response. Here is what the server prints:

```
1 - start
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: csrftoken=ekiwd2n8m6BjVe0Uoyif6OZ7pmWmULDs; _xsrf=2|02c4087f|7e8be522d7bb6404ace2d2117e42deed|1571691550; username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1571694083|23:username-localhost-8888|44:ODk2NzY4Yzg2ZjgyNDRlMzg0ZWEwMjU1MGQ0OTU5NzE=|87587a46d228990c91d93d828c44e2a79155d03332047321e1f882dced5c67dd"; _hp2_id.1263915336=%7B%22userId%22%3A%223410356020127146%22%2C%22pageviewId%22%3A%223017774512831795%22%2C%22sessionId%22%3A%228642071851852288%22%2C%22identity%22%3Anull%2C%22trackerVersion%22%3A%224.0%22%
2 - end
1 - start
```

So it seems to be going through...But the client (Chrome) just receives a blank response:

[image]

Why isn't it returning "Hello, World!" ? When I try it with `telnet` it's the same as well.

Note that this does with with `requests` -- just not `telnet` or `chrome`:

```
>>> print(requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888').text)
Hello, World!
```

It seems to be related to this line:

```
request_data = client_connection.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Reponse shouldn't start with a `\n`

Comment: @MichaelButscher -- thanks, removed.

Comment: with Firefox works correctly - it shows text. Even if response starts with '\n'.

Comment: maybe it doesn't work because you don't send header `content-length: number` with number of bytes in body - so it doesn't know how many bytes you send and it still wait for other data.

Comment: I think that the right line feed is `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: @furas it seems to be related to the request Chrome is sending (with cookies) is larger than 1024 bytes. It seems to be around 1200. Is there a way to receive the message in chunks until it's over? And how can I detect when it's finished?

Comment: I tested code (with `\n` in response) with Chrome and it shows text.

Comment: normally you should read till you get empty line - `\n\n` (or `\r\n\r\n`) - because it is end of header. You can use `while`-loop for this.

Comment: you may right as for large cookies. If I use `.recv(30)` then Firefox and Chrome doesn't display text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said problem can be when browser sends more then 1024 bytes.

This example uses `while True` loop to read in chunk and check if `request_data` ends with `b'\r\n\r\n'` - and it works with `GET` but problem makes `POST` which send body directly after `b'\r\n\r\n'`. To resolve this problem I simply use `.recv(1)` and check `b'\r\n\r\n'` after every bytes but you could try to find better method to check `b'\r\n\r\n'` in `request_data`

```
import socket

HOST, PORT = '', 8888

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)
print(f'Serving HTTP on port {PORT} ...')
while True:
    print ('1 - start')
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()

    request_data = b''

    while True:
        chunk = client_connection.recv(1)
        request_data += chunk
        #print(chunk)
        if request_data.endswith(b'\r\n\r\n'):
            break

    print(request_data.decode('utf-8'))

    client_connection.sendall(b"""HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nHello, World!\n""")
    client_connection.close()
    print ('2 - end')
```

This code reads only header. To read body in `POST` you can use function with bigger value in `recv()` and `POST` should send header `content-length` with size of body so it should be easier to read body then header.

Comment: is this a common pattern on webservers: `while True:
        chunk = client_connection.recv(1)` -- that is, would something like apache use that?

Comment: I think that should be better method to check end of header. You could try to use bigger value in `recv() `and check `if b'\r\n\r\n' in request_data:` and later split `request_data` using `b'\r\n\r\n'` to get header and beginning part of body.

Comment: I used `recv(1)` because it was simpler but I thing real servers may use better method for this. Python has standard module `http` and `http.server` and maybe there is source code in Python so you could check how they resolved it.

Comment: BTW: using `import http.server` `print(http.server.__file__)` you can get path to source code in Python for `http.server`